# Declaring a Tuple whose template type is unknown

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, declaration

I am writing a C++ code to manage the writing of some variables on disk. I've written the entire architecture and what is remaining for the user is the fill a method where he specified how to compute each variable. To do that I've created a template container where the user specifies the variable name and a std::function that computes the variable:

```
template <typename T> struct Container {
    Container<T>(std::string _name, std::function<T()> _f): name(_name), f(_f){

    }

    std::string name;
    std::function<T()> f;
    T *var;

    void assign(int i){
        var[i] = f();
    }
}
```

Then, for each variable the user needs to add he just has to create a new container object. For example:

```
std::string returnTime(){
   // Do stuff and returns time;
   return time;
}

Container<std::string>("time",returnTime);
```

Now my problem is that I need to store all the containers whatever is their type so I thought about using a std::tuple. My actual code looks like:

**Dst.cpp**

```
Dst::registerVariables(){
            variables = std::make_tuple
            (
             Container<unsigned int>("Run", [this](){return ev ? ev -> Run() : -1;}),
             Container<unsigned int>("Event", [this](){return ev ? ev -> Event() : -1;}),
             Container<unsigned int>("UTime", [this](){return ev ? ev -> UTime() : -1;}),
             Container<double>("ThetaS", [this](){return ev ? ev -> fHeader.ThetaS  : 0;})
            );
}
```

Now my actual problem is the declaration of the tuple object "variables" in the header because the type is not known at declaration.

**Dst.hpp**

```
class Dst : public DstAmsBinary{
public:
    Dst( std::string _data ) : DstAmsBinary( _data, MAXRAM){
        std::cout << "init with #" << data.size() << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    void registerVariables();
    auto variables;
};
```

All I could think of was a try at the "auto" keyword but of course that didn't work.

So after all my question comes down to:
How can I build a super-container that stores a list of my template Container objects whatever is their template type.

Maybe storing the list in a Tuple is just the wrong idea. I am looking for suggestions (maybe with other template containers or with a preprocessor macro that computes the type of the tuple...)

Thanks for reading if your reached the end of this message ;-)

Comment: If you know what goes into tuple at compile time - you could declare your tuple as `std::tuple<Container<unsigned int>, Container<double>, ...>`. If you don't know it at compile time - it's not possible. If you know the list of types that go into variables, you could have a vector of variants: `std::vector<boost::variant<Container<unsigned int>, Container<double>>`. If you don't know anything - you could use `std::vector<boost::any>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle this is to have your `Container` class template inherit from a base class that serves as an interface:

```
template <typename T>
class Container : public Base {
  // ....
};
```

Then whenever the variables are registered, everything is registered according to the base type:

```
std::vector<Base> variables;
variables.push_back( Container<unsigned>("Run"  , [this](){return ev ? ev -> Run()   : -1;} ) );
variables.push_back( Container<unsigned>("Event", [this](){return ev ? ev -> Event() : -1;} ) );
// etc.
```

You may need to create smart pointers to these objects and push those back instead, depending on your circumstance (i.e. if `Base` is an abstract interface, which, hopefully, it will be).  You'll also need to think about what type of interface will be allowed via the `Base` class.  But this is a standard way of having a heterogenous collection of objects that can be decided at run-time.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked perfectly. Is this a particular design pattern ?

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a particular design pattern as it is an example of how template techniques and object-oriented design can be incredibly powerful when used together.  Just remember that any instantiation of `Container` is a type; so really all you are doing is created a bunch of derived classes.  So long as they have a common base class, you're golden.  Glad it worked.